# NSTimer called method causes thread break point

Tags: objective-c

Running the class below gives a thread break at the end of the first run of the @selector method timerEvent called by the NSTimer object [ timer ]. The error given is __NSFCTimer, '< error: unknown class>'. It seems to crash after the first iteration of currentNumber to 1.

Any ideas?

```
    //
    //  NumberLooper.m
    //  delegation excersise
    //
    //  Created by Edwin on 7/31/13.
    //  Copyright (c) 2013 Offbeat Software. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "NumberLooper.h"

    @implementation NumberLooper

    -(void) timerEvent: (NSTimer *)timer {
        if (currentNumber < 256)
            currentNumber ++;
        else
            currentNumber = 0;

        NSLog (@"%d", currentNumber);
        [self.delegate numberHasChangedTo:currentNumber];
    }

    -(void) startTimerLoop {
        if (!timer) {
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.020 target:self                 selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
                     NSLog(@"The timer has started");
             }
             else
             {
            NSLog(@"The timer is already running");

        }
    }


    @end
```

Comment: How do you call this class?

Comment: Could you show your .h file? Is the timer retained? Have you assigned the delegate? A couple of minor points: 1. check to see if your delegate is not nil before calling your delegate method. 2. you may want to initialize currentNumber before you start your timer.

Comment: I rewrote the entire program from scratch and the problem seems resolved. I believe it had something to do with creating a new class with the name NumberLooper.h outside the project folder scope in the file manager, deleting and and then creating it again, with the same file name (either that or I created it outside the scope again and dragged it inside). Could this be the reason? Should I have removed or changed a reference of some kind?

Comment: In other words, was there a reference to the NumberLooper.h file created when I created the file outside of the folder scope, which remained after I dragged it into the project scope?

Comment: That could be it. Odd. #importing the .h would compile properly. It makes sense if for some reason the linker wasn't putting NumberLooper into your .ipa. Then whatever code used it would give you that error at run time. Glad it's working.